# New ThreadPoolExecutor for every request, or create a singleton spring bean of ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I have a Restful service that uploads images to S3 bucket. I was thinking of parallel uploads using `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

But should I create a global pool (like `Spring` singleton bean), or create a new `ThreadPoolExecutor` on every request?

Not sure if creating a bean is great idea as `corePoolSize` number of threads will always be alive in the application.
Thanks, in advance.

Comment: If you want to avoid to have unnecessary live threads in the pool, please, consider to use `CachedThreadPool`, which creates thread when it's necessary. But, you should take into account `maxPoolSize`, because by default it's `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: Singleton since once the threads are created, they are waiting for you to give them tasks. Creating threads and removing them isn't a cheap operation.

Comment: Re, "...create a new `ThreadPoolExecutor` on every request?" That would defeat the purpose of using a thread pool.  The _entire point_ of using a thread pool is to prevent your program from having to create and then destroy a new thread for every request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to create Spring `@Bean` like:

```
@Bean
public ExecutorService cachedThreadPool() {
   return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
}
```

Or you can use the inner `ThreadPoolExecutor`. It all depends on your needs.